# How to add characters to a specific element in a list without overwriting the entire list?

Tags: python, list

Okay, so my original problem was adding characters to a specific element in a list, but then I encountered the problem of my fix overwriting my entire list, leaving me with the edited element.

My code

```
listy = ['item_1','item_2','item_3']

listy = ['('+listy[1]+')']

print(listy)
>'(item_2)'
```

I understand why this is happening, I just don't know how to also add back the rest of the list (non-manually)

I tried doing:

```
listy = [listy[0:1] + '('+listy[1]+')' + listy[2:]]
```

And got back a `TypeError`, which I expected, but wanted to make sure it didn't work first.

This was all I tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you got your problem correctly, you want to update listy[1] with the new variable you want.

you can do it easy by assign it to the index like that

```py
listy = ['item_1','item_2','item_3']
listy[1] = f"({listy[1]})"
print(listy)
```

the output will be :

```
['item_1', '(item_2)', 'item_3']
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! This helped me get to the solution I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

Assign to the list index, not the variable holding the entire list.

```
listy[1] = '('+listy[1]+')'
```

Comment: I'd change it to f-strings, to not do multiple concatenations. `listy[1] = f"({listy[1]})"`

Comment: This is so short I think the original form is clearer. In the f-string it's hard to see that you're just adding 2 characters. The number of concatenations is negligible.

Comment: I eventually remembered that f-string works on lists (with the help of the answer I marked here) and got the solution I wanted.

Comment: f-string works with almost any expression.